# How to programmatically invoke an org-capture template

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

Let's say I have the following template added to `org-capture`:

```el
(defvar my/org-todo-template
  "* %^{NUMBER} - %^{DESCR} [%]
** Contacts
** Fotos
** Tasks
*** TODO Task a
*** TODO Task b")

(defun add-list-to-list (dst src)
  "Similar to `add-to-list', but accepts a list as 2nd argument"
  (set dst
       (append (eval dst) src)))

(add-list-to-list 'org-capture-templates `(("t" "Todo" entry (file "/path/to/file.org")
                                            ,my/org-todo-template
                                            :empty-lines-before 1)))
```

How can I invoke this in another function with the variables passed by argument?

Something like this is what I'm looking for:

```el
(defun test-capture (NUMBER DESCRIPTION) (org-capture "t" NUMBER DESCRIPTION))
```